# Shimura lift is isomorphic iff twisted Hecke $L$ function does not vanish at central point

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $S_{2k}(1)$ and $S_{k+1/2}(4)$ denote the set of modular forms of weight $2k$ for $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ and weight $k+1/2$ for the congruence subgroup $\Gamma_0(4)$, respectively. Consider the Kohnen plus space
$$ S_{k+1/2}^+(4):= \lbrace g = \sum_{n\geq1} a_g(n) e^{2\pi inz} \in S_{k+1/2}(4) : a_g(n)=0 \text{ unless } (-1)^kn\equiv 0,1 \bmod 4 \rbrace. $$

For a fundamental discriminant $D$ with $(-1)^kD>0$, consider the Shimura-Kohnen lift
$ \mathcal{S}_{D,k}^+ : S_{k+1/2}^+(4) \longrightarrow S_{2k}(1) $ defined by
$$ \sum_{n\geq1} a_g(n) e^{2\pi inz} \mapsto \sum_{n\geq1} \left(\sum{d|n} \left(\frac{D}{d}\right) d^{k-1} a_g(n^2|D|/d^2)  \right) e^{2\pi inz}. $$

**Question:**(Edited) I need to prove the following equivalence -

*If $\mathcal{S}_{D,k}$ is an isomorphism for all $D$ and $k$ iff and only if $L(f,D,k)$ is non-zero for all $f$ (normalized Hecke eigenform) and $D$; where $L(f,D,k)= \sum_{n\geq1} \left(\frac{D}{n}\right)a_f(n) n^{-k}$.*

(This particular version of the equivalence is taken from this [2023 paper](https://www.worldscientific.com/doi/10.1142/S1793042123500100) by Kohnen).
I may have misunderstood the statement of the equivalence (which is to be proved), in the sense that I have a doubt in the statement itself as follows -   the equivalence is stated for a single $\mathcal{S}_{D,k}$ right? i.e., for a fixed $D$ and $k$? (Because we know a linear combination of Shimura lifts will give an isomorphism between the two spaces). So, what does actually the second part mean? $L(f,D,k)$ should be non-zero for all normalized Hecke eigenforms in $S_{2k}(1)$?

**Attempt:** I know that $a_g(|D|)^2$ and $L(f,D,k)$ are connected by Waldspurger's formula; so if $f$ is a normalized Hecke eigenform and $g$ is the associated half-integral weight form under the Shimura correspondence, then $a_g(|D|)^2 \neq 0$ iff $L(f,D,k)\neq0$. But how to connect this?

Comment: The phrasing of your question is strange. Your "question" seems to be a statement, and your "doubt" seems to be your question.

Comment: @Kimball My phrasing was not correct, thank you. I have edited the question accordingly. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: @Kimball In Indian English, the word "doubt" is often used to mean "question". This can be quite confusing on MO and MSE, since in other forms of English, "doubt" indicates distrust or disbelief in a statement, whereas this connotation is not present in Indian English; instead, there is a connotation of uncertainty.

Comment: @PeterHumphries My comment was based on the formatting of the original version of the question.